# Check if XML element is existing in loop

Tags: php, xml, xpath

For a website i'm making i need to get data from an external XML file.
I load the data like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$url = 'http://myurl/results/xml/12345';

if (!$doc->load($url)) 
{
    echo json_encode(array('error'=> 'error')); 
    exit;
}

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$program_date = $xpath->query('//game/date');
```

Then i use a foreach loop to get all the data

```
if($program_date){
    foreach($program_date as $node){
        $programArray['program_date'][]  = $node->nodeValue;
    }
}
```

The problem i'm having is that sometimes a certain game doesn't have a date.
So when a game doesn't have a date, i just want it to put "-", instead of the date from the XML file. My problem is that i don't know how to check if a date is present in the data.

I used a lot of ways like isset, !isset, else, !empty, empty

```
$teamArray['program_kind'][]  = "-";
```

but noting works...
Can someone help me with this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know to much about php, but try to do somthin like: before do `$programArray['program_date'][]  = $node->nodeValue;` is better to safe the value in an aux `var = $node->nodeValue;` then make the validation, somthing like.. `if(aux == null/"") then $teamArray['program_kind'][]  = "-";`

Comment: Thanks for your response! But i think the main problem is that an empty value (the whole element doesn't exist) won't become a node...? When i check the lengte of $program_date it's 67, but there are 70 entries in the XML file

Comment: Do one thing @Rhyvon , edit your question with the XML file that arrives, in this way, we will see how is the structure of the xml, and will be easy to search a solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate the `game` elements, use them as a context and fetch the data with additional XPath expressions.

But one thing first. Use `DOMXPath::evaluate()`. `DOMXPath::query()` only supports location paths. It can only return a node list. But XPath expressions can return scalar values, too.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$games = $xpath->evaluate('//game');
```

The result of `//game` will always be a `DOMNodeList` object. It can be an empty list, but you can directly iterate it. A condition like `if ($games)` will always be true.

```
foreach ($games as $game) {
```

Now that you have the `game` element node, you can use it as an context to fetch other data.

```
  $date = $xpath->evaluate('string(date)', $game);
```

`string()` casts the first node of the location path into a string. If it can not match a node, it will return an empty string. Check `normalize-space()` if you want to remove whitespaces at the same time.

You can validate if the `game` element has a `date` node using `count()`.

```
  $hasDate = $xpath->evaluate('count(date) > 0', $game);
```

The result of this XPath expression is always a boolean.